# Change memory address content with ddd

Tags: memory, ddd-debugger

How can I change the content of a memory address using ddd?

Comment: I already edited the tags, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ddd runs gdb underneath, so in the gdb window you can just type something like:

```
set *((int *) 0x822b2ec) = 0x100
```

See [How to modify memory contents using GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305164/how-to-modify-memory-contents-using-gdb)