# In gdb, how can I write a string to memory?

Tags: string, gdb

It is quite straightforward to write ints or hexadecimals to a memory address with gdb:

```
(gdb) set {int}0x08040000 = 42
(gdb) set {int}0x08040000 = 0xffffffff
```

But how can I write chars or entire strings in a similarly simple fashion to memory? Right now I have to resort to translating the string to hex and then entering that, which is time consuming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Say you have the following program:

```
int main(void){
    char[] person = "Bob";
    char[] p2 = "Alice";

    printf("Hello %s\n");
}
```

With GDB you could set a breakpoint in main, and change the person's name via:

```
(gdb) set main::person = { 'S', 'a', 'm', 0x00 }
```

or more susinctly

```
(gdb) set main::person = "Sam"
```

If you want to set memory directly use:

```
set {char [4]} 0x08040000 = "Ace"
```

I'm assuming that since you're poking memory with gdb you know what you're doing, so you know about setting the null bytes for strings etc.  Keep in mind if you are trying to change values for an array and you try to put in a string that is longer than what was originally allocated, you have a really good chance that you're going to corrupt memory.  (example trying to set main::person to "Dilbert" is going to cause problems

Comment: Maybe I should add here that I need this for an exercise for school where we have to use the disassembled code and gdb only to find out what the program does, so I do not have source code available.

Comment: Although Paul's answer is easier, and for the most part better,  I would argue that my answer is more correct. You are calling strcpy to do your dirty work - which 99% of the time is fine.  But what happens if you're trying to reverse the strcpy function itself?  What if for some reason you don't have access to strcpy?  My last set example would work regardless.

Answer (score 11):

Use `strcpy()`

```
(gdb) p malloc(20)
$3 = (void *) 0x6ce81808
(gdb) p strcpy($3, "my string")
$4 = 1827149832
(gdb) x/s $3
0x6ce81808: "my string"
```

Comment: Although this is a nice and trick, strcpy is not a gdb command.  What happens when you don't have access to strcpy for some reason (when reversing malware, this is a valid assumption).

Comment: I wasn't aware you could define your own commands.  Wouldn't it just be much easier to say set {char [4]} 0xDEADBEEF = "Sam" then to write your own function?  Also, you can use gdb to debug more than C/C++ (Go, ADA, assembly, etc), so strcpy isn't always going to be there.

Comment: I used you answer for creating and assinging a string. Debugged program was a glib program and crashed on g_free(), so I had to use g_malloc() instead of malloc(). Step 3 looked like this: set ((HFMarkInfo*)hf_state->marks->data)->options = $3