# How can I write bytes to memory using gdb?

Tags: memory, gdb

Related to this question: [In gdb, how can I write a string to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503057/in-gdb-how-can-i-write-a-string-to-memory)

However, my question is regarding how to write non-ASCII characters as well, which I'm having trouble with.

Not only does it seem like I have to specify the number of characters I want to write with

`set {char[<number of characters>]}`, but I don't seem able to escape characters in my string.

Consider:

```
set {char [5]} 0x618204 = "ABCD"
```

This should be equivalent:

```
set {char [5]} 0x618204 = "ABC\x44"
```

There is no error, but this treats the string as something else entirely, I'm not even sure what this does.

How can I write a string with escaped characters like this, I want some way to write arbitrary bytes to memory, preferably without needing to tell GDB beforehand how many bytes I intend to write.

I'd like something simple like:

```
set 0x618204 = \x41\x42\x43\x44\x45
```

This should write the bytes 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 to memory, starting at the address 0x618204.

Am I just missing the correct syntax for this, or doesn't it exist? Is there some extension to GDB that can do it? gef, peda?

Comment: If you can get those bytes into a file, the [restore](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html) command may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in memory with GDB using the **set** command:

Here is an example of how to change a single byte in memory with GDB:

```
pwndbg> x/bx 0x7fffffffdb7f
0x7fffffffdb7f: 0x30

pwndbg> set *0x7fffffffdb7f=0x00

pwndbg> x/bx 0x7fffffffdb7f
0x7fffffffdb7f: 0x00
```

You can also write multiple bytes, but you have to be aware of endianess.

```
pwndbg> set *0x7fffffffdb78=0x00414243
pwndbg> x/s 0x7fffffffdb78
0x7fffffffdb78: "CBA"

pwndbg> set *0x7fffffffdb78=0x0068732f6e69622f
pwndbg> x/s 0x7fffffffdb78
0x7fffffffdb78: "/bin/sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no error, but this treats the string as something else entirely

No, it doesn't:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file t.c, line 3.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:3
3     char buf[] = "abcd";
(gdb) n
4     void *p = buf;
(gdb) n
5     return 0;
(gdb) p p
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdb93
(gdb) p {char[4]}p
$2 = "abcd"
(gdb) set {char[4]}p = "ABC\x44"
Too many array elements
```

The error here is because `char[4]` doesn't account for terminating `NUL`.

```
(gdb) set {char[5]}p = "ABC\x44"
(gdb) p buf
$3 = "ABCD"
```

Voila!